# What is a more elegant way to write this piece of code?

Tags: java

I have my method in another class(let us call it "MethodSumArray" as follows :

```
public static int [] sumArray(int [] a, int [] b) {
     int [] c = new int [a.length];
     for(int i = 0 ; i<a.length;i++)
         c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
     System.out.println("The sum of the array is  :" + Arrays.toString(c));
     return c;
}
```

In my Main class (let us call it "Calculus" ) I can call this method by using the following piece of code :

```
MethodSumArray.sumArray(a,b);
```

This prints on my screen the result wanted for example :

```
int [] a = {1,2,3};
int [] b = {1,2,3};
```

the result will be : `[2,4,6] as expected`

My question is Can it be called in another way without writing "MethodSumArray.sumArray" ?

**EDIT**

I modified the Main class by putting an overloading method as in :

```
Whatever w =  new Whatever (a,b,c,d)
w.sumArray(a,b);
```

This will also bring up the correct result, but this solution made me wonder, what is more practical\correct way to do for this type of exercises:

1. Make only one Main class where I have my method in order to call it as I want without calling another class (ClassName.SumArray(a,b)), *or*
2. Make one Main Class and then an auxiliary class in witch i declare my methods
   and then make use of the overloading to call out whatever method i need in order to do my program?  (Whatever w =  new Whatever (a,b,c,d) ---> w.sumArray(a,b))

Comment: Are you asking if you could call a method without mentioning it by name? The answer is "no". There's also no operator overloading.

Comment: Consider a more meaningful class/method name within the context of your app.  For example, since you mentioned `Calculus` as a class name, consider changing `MethodSumArray` to `VectorMath` which has a `public static int[] sum(int[] a, int[] b)` method.  Invoking the method as `int[] result = VectorMath.sum(a, b)` becomes much more readable/intuitive.

Comment: I am asking if I can call the method sumArray present in class MethodSumArray , in the Main class MainCalculus , without calling the class name "MethodSumArray.sumArray(a,b); " , these two being present in the same package

Comment: Concerning your edit: *it depends* and is a matter of style and taste. If you have many methods which do not *directly* belong to the concern of your main class, separate them. Saving some bytes to type does not necessarily makes the code better and more readable.

Comment: Thank you Martin Nyolt(and of course all others) for your replies , the methods in this case concern the main class so I keep them in the same class, so far I noticed 3 ways to write my code for the given question 1. use of overloads , 2. use of import static class Method , 3 . call class name and method .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As these are two differenct classes, you *have to* qualify the call to `sumArray` (or use a static import as already suggested). It does not matter whether they are in the same package or not - only the class matters for scope. 
Packages help in structuring your classes and method *protection* (cf. package-private access).

That is, Java packages do *not* add any additional scoping.
Maybe you compare packages to C++ namespaces, which do add scoping blocks. But these are different concepts and should not be mixed.

Of course, you could also declare a local method which forwards your call:

```
private static int[] sumArray(int[] a, int[] b) {
    return MethodSumArray.sumArray(a, b);
}
```

But this is probably one case where static imports are the lesser evil.

Answer (score 1):

You can import your method "statically" in that way :

**EDIT:**

```
import static your.package.name.MethodSumArray.sumArray;
```

and then you can call it like that :

```
sumArray(a,b);
```

Comment: I use eclipse , the classes are in the same package, your suggestion gives me the following error : "the import MethodSumArray cannot be resolved"

Answer (score 1):

Try

`import static your.package.tree.MethodSumArray.sumArray;`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Petar, you can use static import, although using static imports can make your code more difficult to read, so they should be used with caution.

You can define your `MethodSumArray` class as follows :

```
package testPack;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MethodSumArray {
    public static int[] sumArray(int[] a, int[] b) {
        int[] c = new int[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
        System.out.println("The sum of the array is  :" + Arrays.toString(c));
        return c;
    }
}
```

And then in you main class :

```
package testPack;

import static testPack.MethodSumArray.sumArray;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sumArray(a, b); 
    }
}
```

When shoud you use static imports ? The Java [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/static-import.html) says :

> **Very sparingly!** Only use it when you'd otherwise be tempted to declare
>   local copies of constants.